# Draw dropshadow using Direct2D

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, direct2d

I need to render a dropshadow of bitmap A onto bitmap B using Direct2D.

More specifically, A is 32-bit with alpha-transparency, i.e. some pixels can be transparent. B (also 32-bit) contains another image, i.e. it can't be assumed empty.

Can someone provide a working example of how to do that?
Preferably as a method that takes blur amount, distance, color and opacity of the dropshadow as parameters.

The C++ code I'm trying to convert is the below from MS. But I'm not sure about converting the C++ syntax and also the D2D2 libraries in Delphi XE2 seem to be incomplete.

```
ComPtr<ID2D1Effect> shadowEffect;
m_d2dContext->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1Shadow, &shadowEffect);

shadowEffect->SetInput(0, bitmap);

// Shadow is composited on top of a white surface to show opacity.
ComPtr<ID2D1Effect> floodEffect;
m_d2dContext->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1Flood, &floodEffect);

floodEffect->SetValue(D2D1_FLOOD_PROP_COLOR, D2D1::Vector4F(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));

ComPtr<ID2D1Effect> affineTransformEffect;
m_d2dContext->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D12DAffineTransform, &affineTransformEffect);

affineTransformEffect->SetInputEffect(0, shadowEffect.Get());

D2D1_MATRIX_3X2_F matrix = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(20, 20));

affineTransformEffect->SetValue(D2D1_2DAFFINETRANSFORM_PROP_TRANSFORM_MATRIX, matrix);

ComPtr<ID2D1Effect> compositeEffect;
m_d2dContext->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1Composite, &compositeEffect);

compositeEffect->SetInputEffect(0, floodEffect.Get());
compositeEffect->SetInputEffect(1, affineTransformEffect.Get());
compositeEffect->SetInput(2, bitmap);

m_d2dContext->BeginDraw();
m_d2dContext->DrawImage(compositeEffect.Get());
m_d2dContext->EndDraw();
```

Comment: Perhaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/drop-shadow might be of interest?

Comment: I saw that but can't figure out how to convert it to Delphi :-(

Comment: Maybe I can have a look at it tomorrow, if no one beats me to it. (Assuming this Q isn't closed by then, because it might be considered a "please write the code for me" kind of question, and such are often rather poorly received.)

Comment: Well, I tried. Seems like the Delphi libraries for XE2 don't have all the declarations/types I need for this. Also, I'm not sure about the C++ syntax. So I'm not really making progress on this one. I feel like I am missing/misunderstanding something.

Comment: I have skimmed through the documentation and believe you are right: (1) this requires more Win32/DirectX declarations than are offered by RAD Studio, so you will need to define some constants and types (including interfaces) yourself, or find some Delphi translations on the WWW (there seems to be at least one such). (2) Worse: you probably cannot use the Windows 7 `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget`-based approach to Direct2D that almost all Delphi devs use. ...

Comment: (cont.) Instead, you need a [Direct2D device context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/devices-and-device-contexts) which takes some effort to setup. I imagine these steps to be fairly straight-forward, but unfortunately quite time consuming the first time.

Comment: So, regarding your update: converting the code you show isn't much work, but obtaining the `m_d2dContext` pointer needed before this point is.

Comment: I'd be happy with a version that works in Delphi XE2/windows 10, just to clarify. Not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: I understand. And it would work even on Windows 7, I think, if the Windows 7 system has been updated with the "Platform Update". Basically, I think you "only" need to implement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/devices-and-device-contexts in order to get the Direct2D device context; then you can use the code in your snippet.